# Update at the same time

Tags: mysql, xampp

When 2 client tries to update the same row at the same time only one is submitted and the other one is rejected so i want to create a queue to update one by one and sorry for bad English

I’m student I don’t know how to do is there any other way

I created java system for inventory i have store when 2 client tries to buy the same product at The same time , it must update the row for example product_quantity =10 If client 1 and client 2 tries to buy at the same time client 1 buy 2 it must be 10-2=8 and client 2 buy 3 it must 8-3=5 but the result appears 8 or 7 it mean accept only one this my code (select product_quantity from store where store_id = barcode)
If quantity > 0 { ( update store set products_quantity = ( sumquantity - quantitytobuy) where storeid = barcode 
}

Comment: why other is getting rejected ? are you getting any error ? Show us your code, detailing the relevant sql portions

Comment: As mentioned in answers to related questions here on stackoverflow, the update query is atomic: if two clients attempt to update a record, there'll be two updates; none of them is "rejected".

Comment: A real 'update' shouldn't be a problem. For instance: `value = value+1` will work because two queries containing this are executed one after the other. The total opposite is an 'overwrite', like: `value = 10`. Then the value will be that of the last query. A final case is 'retrieve-edit-store'. if you let a client retrieve a value from the database, hold on to it, change it, and then store it, then only the last stored edit will be in the database. You have to make clear what kind of 'UPDATE' you're talking about. Note that a queue never seem to be the solution.

Comment: To create a queue would be to try to synchronise actions between two unconnected threads. The more durable way is for for the client code to catch and exception, and then decide how best to take action (which might be repeating the query). If the error is a 'Deadlock error', then the application needs to decide the action to be taken because there is no right solution that works for every desired user application. Your english is fine, no need to apologize. Your question could use more detail however.

Comment: I created java system for inventory i have store when 2 client tries  to buy the same product at The same time , it must update the row for example product_quantity =10 If client 1 and client 2 tries to buy at the same time client 1 buy 2 it must be 10-2=8 and client 2 buy 3 it must 8-3=5 but the result appears 8 or 7 it mean accept  only one this my code (select product_quantity from store where store_id = barcode) ( update store set products_quantity = ( sumquantity - quantitytobuy) where storeid = barcode